# create variable based on variable and column condition - pyspark

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

I'm trying to create a new variable based on a simple variable `ModelType` and a df variable `model`.

Currently I'm doing it in this way

```
if ModelType == 'FRSG':
    df=df.withColumn(MODEL_NAME+'_veh', F.when(df["model"].isin(MDL_CD), df["ford_cd"]))
elif ModelType == 'TYSG':
    df=df.withColumn(MODEL_NAME+'_veh', F.when(df["model"].isin(MDL_CD), df["toyota_cd"]))
else:
    df=df.withColumn(MODEL_NAME+'_veh', F.when(df["model"].isin(MDL_CD), df["cm_cd"]))
```

I have tried this as well

```
df=df.withColumn(MODEL_NAME+'_veh', F.when((ModelType == 'FRSG') &(df["model"].isin(MDL_CD)), df["ford_cd"]))
```

but since the variable `ModelType` is not a column so it gives an error

```
TypeError: condition should be a Column
```

Is there any other efficient method also to perform the same?

Answer (score 2):

You can also use a dict that holds the possible mappings for `ModelType` and use it like this:

```
model_mapping = {"FRSG": "ford_cd", "TYSG": "toyota_cd"}

df = df.withColumn(
    MODEL_NAME + '_veh', 
    F.when(df["model"].isin(MDL_CD), df[model_mapping.get(ModelType, "cm_cd")])
)
```

Answer (score 1):

I would probably use a variable for the column to be chosen in the `then` part:

```
if ModelType == 'FRSG':
    x = "ford_cd"
elif ModelType == 'TYSG':
    x = "toyota_cd"
else:
    x = "cm_cd"

df=df.withColumn(MODEL_NAME+'_veh', F.when(df["model"].isin(MDL_CD), df[x]))
```